# Ao enumerar uma lista, é preciso utilizar obrigatoriamente números?

Tags: significado

Recentemente o presidente Jair Bolsonaro postou uma [publicação no Twitter](https://twitter.com/jairbolsonaro/status/1164901233699823616?s=20) com o seguinte título:

> **Enumerando** mais alguns avanços do governo (…)

Abaixo do título, ele fez uma lista utilizando letras em vez de número.
Pesquisando em alguns dicionários, observei que dois deles definem *enumerar* como listar, especificar e expor, porém fala nada sobre ser com número, letras e/ou caracteres.

Afinal de contas, posso *enumerar* uma lista usando letras ou símbolos?

Comment: Ultimamente o site está pouco movimentado 

Comment: Pouquíssimo, menos de uma pergunta a cada dois dias. Por que será que o site não decola? São dezenas de milhões de lusófonos conectados à internet. Só posso imaginar que seja reflexo de falantes um sua maioria pouco interessados no próprio idioma (além do que são obrigados a saber para exames e congêneres) e do português não ser uma língua estrangeira particularmente popular (e também de termos pouco conteúdo, ok, especialmente em inglês).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não há nenhuma prescrição em gramáticas que obrigue um autor a lançar mão de números ao *enumerar*, a despeito da etimologia da palavra. Entretanto, há muitas palavras na língua portuguesa (e em todas as outras) em que um sentido se altera ao longo do tempo. Como exemplo, é perfeitamente lícito *embarcar* em um carro ou avião, embora não sejam barcos, ou *espalhar* algo que não seja palha.

Lamento não ter fontes fiáveis para citar, mas o cerne do problema é que os gramáticos não fizeram recomendação a respeito do uso deste verbo, então não há recomendação para citar.

Comment: Por que essa é uma resposta *community wiki*?

Comment: Porque se alguém tiver uma fonte para citar, pode inseri-las. Se este é um uso incorreto do mecanismo de _community wiki_, estou contente em remover a resposta completamente, mas não me parece irregular.

Comment: Não creio que seja um uso incorreto. Penso que não precisava ser community, mas de fato é uma maneira válida de sinalizar que a resposta pede algum complemento ou aprimoramento.